# How to get skew angle from image

Tags: android, tesseract, leptonica

I am facing problem to  get the skew angle from image .I am using tesseract api for image processing. I have searched a lot on web but no appropriate solution found. I have used following code:

```
Pix test=ReadFile.readBitmap(bitmap.createBitmap(400, 400, Config.ARGB_8888));
float angle=Skew.findSkew(test);
```

from above code I get angle value 0.0. Please help me to resolve this problem or show the
right direction to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 2):

```
TessBaseAPI baseApi = new TessBaseAPI();
baseApi.setImage(bitmap);    
Pix test = baseApi.getThresholdedImage();
float a = Skew.findSkew(test);
```

Sometimes get 0.0, generally work. But I'm not sure of the correct.

Answer (score 1):

```
 public static float findSkew(Pix pixs, float sweepRange, 
                              float sweepDelta, int sweepReduction,
                              int searchReduction, float searchMinDelta)
```

Your `findSkew(...)` does not have the correct parameters.