# Leptonica findSkew returns 0.0

Tags: java, android, image-processing, skew, leptonica

I am facing same problem with Leptonica library on Android as [How to get skew angle from image](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20866495/3608132)
I tried both of these methods - with one parameter and with six parameters, where I tried multiple combinations.

```
Float s = Skew.findSkew(ReadFile.readBitmap(image));
Toast.makeText(this, s.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Result 0.0

```
Float s = Skew.findSkew(ReadFile.readBitmap(image),40.0f,1.0f,4,1,0.04f);
Toast.makeText(this, s.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Result 0.0 too

Does anybody know how to set these parameters without getting 0.0 or is there other simple library that could same function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For those who have same problem, try to use binarized image from Leptonica.
I used binarization from Catalano framework and it didn't work, but when I applied binarization from Leptonica on the image and use findSkew, it works!

Comment: I tried your suggested solution to find skew angle after binarizing the bitmap returns 0.0. Any solution to get the exact skew angle.If possible share your code.

Comment: I have that code above. Sometimes it returns me 0.0 too, it could be caused by low number of text lines...